# Pass a variable while calling the function from onclick="getTagname(text)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

my code:

```js
function getTagname(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
  if (e.button == 2) {
    var text = $(e.target).attr('id'); // getting the element id and stored in var text
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <span class="menuItem" onclick="getTagname(text);">get element tagname</span>
  <br>
  <span class="menuItem">get id</span>
  <br>
  <span class="menuItem" onclick="reload();">refresh</span>
</div>
```

I want to pass the `text` variable as a parameter while calling the function `onclick="getTagname(text);"`

But not working.

I tried everything from my perspective, and does lot of things.

At the end couldn't found anything useful for me.

Thank You in Advance...

Comment: Where are you expecting `text` to be read from? It's not defined anywhere. And even if it were, with your current setup (of inline events) it would have to be a global variable, which is not ideal. You'd do far better to use this as an opportunity to move to centralised events via `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access variables between events generally requires defining the values with global scope, which is bad practice.

A much better approach is to store the value in a `data` attribute which is accessible to all location where it is required. It also means you can avoid the use of ugly and outdated `onX` event attributes. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $doc = $(document);

  $('.get-id').on('click', () => {
    let elementId = $doc.data('last-id');
    console.log(elementId);
  });

  $('refresh').on('click', () => window.location.reload());

  $(document).on('mousedown', e => {
    if (e.button === 2) {
      $doc.data('last-id', e.target.id);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <span class="menuItem get-id">get element id</span><br />
  <span class="menuItem" id="foo">get id - right click me</span><br />
  <span class="menuItem" id="bar">get id - right click me</span><br />
  <span class="menuItem" id="fizz">get id - right click me</span><br />
  <span class="menuItem" id="buzz">get id - right click me</span><br />
  <span class="menuItem refresh">refresh</span>
</div>
```